# Export data from PHP to Excel with comma issue

Tags: php, excel

My database:

[image: My database]

I am having a issue exporting my data to excel due to the comma in the "description" field in my database.

Here is my code:

```
<?php 
include 'database.php';
if (isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $filename = 'uploads/'.strtotime("now").'.csv';
    $fp = fopen($filename, "w");
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM data";
    $linkSql = mysqli_query($link,$sql) or die(mysqli_error($link));
    $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($linkSql);

    $seperator ="";
    $comma = "";
    foreach ($row as $name => $value) {
        $seperator .= $comma . '' .str_replace('','""',$name);
        $comma = ",";
    }
    $seperator .="\n";
    fputs($fp, $seperator);

    mysqli_data_seek($linkSql, 0);

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($linkSql)){
    $seperator ="";
    $comma = "";
    foreach ($row as $name => $value) {
        $seperator .= $comma . '' .str_replace('','""',$value);
        $comma = ",";
    }
    $seperator .="\n";
    fputs($fp, $seperator);
    }        fclose($fp);
} ?>

<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form method="post" action="export.php">
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="export">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

And here is the data after I export to excel:

[image: Data after export to excel.]

Comment: Stop using homebrew solutions that don't work properly, and use PHP's built-in [fputcsv()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php) function which is written to handle commas correctly

Answer (score 5):

The issue is you're implementing something needlessly and have to solve all the tedious issues others before you have already addressed.

There's a wonderful built in function called `fputcsv()` that handles seperators and enclosures to escape your content fields very well.

Here's the link to the php doc page: http://php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php

- Learn it
- Love it
- Live it

Answer (score 0):

If you need anything over an above simple reading then maybe have a look at [PHPExcel](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel)